# Eclipse PDT content assist for PHP just stopps working randomly

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, code-assist

My problem is, that my Eclipse PDT randomly looses PHP content assist. It happened about a dozen times now and I can't figure out, what causes this. It used to happen about once in two weeks. I install a plugin or just close Eclipse and sometimes, when I start it up next time, it looses basic PHP assit, like "in_array()". But all project specific assistance works fine though.

I went through a lot of tips, checking my window > prefs > php content assist, checking if PHP support is added to the project, checking my project's .buildpath, making a clean build, starting Eclipse with -clean option. These things just don't help.
What I used to do (and will do now) is to restore an Eclipse backup, meaning I have to restore my pdt_workspace and my Eclipse install folder *both* or PHP assist will not work. I've tried restoring parts of these folders or just on of these, but it seems, I have to restore both of them to get content assist back. I went through this a dozen times now, so fortunately I make weekly backups. ;-)

I don't know, what makes these problems happen. Does anyone have some similar problem or any idea about this?

*/sorry for bad english/*

UPDATE:

I don't know what's going on really, but I got PHP assist working again, two times. First time it started working I've been a lot of install/uninstall and it just came back working. But I've lost it again for no reason. This time, I've uninstalled Yiiclipse and Zen Coding plugin and PHP assist started working. But I reinstalled them and PHP assist is still working! WTF?!
I can't see any logic in this....

Comment: it sounds like an unstable or incompatible plugin... I've been hurt by it :) At the end i've moved from eclipse to PHPStorm and sublime text 2 but they are both paid... Anyway you may try to remove some plugins and see if it solves anything. Just my two cents :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem. After a lot of testing I ended up removing Zen Coding and Yiiclipse both and doing a clean + build on all projects. This seem to solve my problems and give back PHP code assist.
The downside is, I don't have Yiiclipse and Zen Coding now....

Answer (score 0):

Well, after much grief with this I opened up Eclipse, and right click the project, go to Add PHP support... and voilá.  That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue due to Upgrade from Helios -> Luna & Content Assist, Key references, variables etc. suddenly stopped working. This was due to incompatible db structure in h2 database from older one.

To resolve this, just remove the data or files from : 
<your workspace directory>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2